# QObject::connect not working - Signal not found with function syntax

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create a very basic dialog with Qt:

```
QDialog *inputDialog = new QDialog(g.ParentWidget);
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(inputDialog);
inputDialog->setWindowTitle(to_qstring(p_strTitle));
inputDialog->setLayout(layout);

QDialogButtonBox *buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox(
  QDialogButtonBox::Cancel | QDialogButtonBox::Ok, inputDialog);
layout->addWidget(buttonBox);

QObject::connect(buttonBox, &QDialogButtonBox::accepted, inputDialog, &QDialog::accept);
QObject::connect(buttonBox, &QDialogButtonBox::rejected, inputDialog, &QDialog::reject);

inputDialog->setModal(true);
if (inputDialog->exec() != QDialog::Accepted) {
  return gcnew array<int>(0);
}
```

Where `g.ParentWidget` is a `QWidget` from elsewhere. This code is in a static method, outside of a class.

When I run this, I get:

```
QObject::connect: signal not fount in QDialogButtonBox
```

I tried looking for similar issues but I only found answers for trivial issues with old Qt syntax, or when `signals:` was missing, which is not the case there.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? What could be causing this?

---

This code is called within a C++/CLR project, in a piece of codes that gets called from C#, but I have no issue with similar stuff using `QMessageBox`.

Comment: As you've stated yourself, this type of error message is associated with the 'old' `connect` syntax at runtime.  If the signal really didn't exist then any `connect` call using the new syntax would fail to compile.  Can you edit your question to show the full error message(s) verbatim (it should include the signal name).  You could also [install a message handler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler) that you can break on under a debugger to isolate the code generating the error.

Comment: Is it possible the code shown is called *before* `main` is entered?  Or, at least, before Qt has been fully initialized?  Looking through the Qt source it appears the error message seen can result from the new signal/slot syntax but only if the address of `buttonBox->staticMetaObject` evaluates to null -- which should never happen under normal circumstances.

Comment: @G.M. No, the code cannot be called before `main`. This is a plugin for another software that also uses Qt. As I said, I have no issue with other Qt stuffs that uses signals/slots (I assume) internally such as `QMessageBox`. I also do not have anything more than the message I put (it is from the log of the other softwares). I solved the issue by using old Qt syntax. This seems to be related to some ABI issues (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43556 https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61710), probably due to the C++/CLR nature of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you did not specify the compiler, OS, and I also encountered such an error, I advise you to switch to the old syntax,

```
QObject::connect(buttonBox, &QDialogButtonBox::accepted, inputDialog, &QDialog::accept);
QObject::connect(buttonBox, &QDialogButtonBox::rejected, inputDialog, &QDialog::reject);
```

change to

```
QObject::connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), inputDialog, SLOT(accept()));
QObject::connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(rejected()), inputDialog, SLOT(reject()));
```

such a permutation solved my problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Someone pointed me to some Qt bugs (see my comment on the question) which indeed show such behavior. I assume it is due to the C++/CLR nature of the project.

Comment: If the code compiles with the functor syntax, then there's no point in moving to the old SIGNAL/SLOT macro syntax. In fact, it will likely only increase the risk of such mistakes. 

If moving to the old syntax actually fixed it, then "by accident". The issue is likely a naming collision of class names and QObject::connect() picking one randomly.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if there are 2 different classes with the same name and QObject::connect picks the "wrong" one at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add Q_OBJECT macro in your class first to use slots and signals in QT.

Comment: ? Both sender and receiver here are classes from Qt.

Comment: "The Q_OBJECT macro must appear in the private section of a class definition that declares its own signals and slots or that uses other services provided by Qt's meta-object system."-qt help document

Comment: Senders and receivers need the macro, not the one connecting them. That can even be a free function (like main()).